# Elements of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb F_{p^n})$ of order $p^k$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

Let $p > 2$ be a prime number and $n\ge 1$ an integer, and consider the group $G = \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb F_{p^n})$ of order $p^n(p^{2n} - 1)$. Let us denote by $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ (the "inner elements" of $G$; feel free to come up with a more creative name) the elements of $G$ whose order is some power of $p$. Do these elements constitute a subgroup?

Comment: It's not true for $k=1$. I don't see why it's true for other values of $k$.

Comment: A short precision: I want to look at the set of all elements of whose order is *any* power of $p$. It does not have to be the same power for all elements.

Comment: That's too large, larger than any $p$-Sylow subgroups. If it is a group, it must contain an element of order prime to $p$.

Comment: ${\rm Inn}(G)$ is a very bad name indeed, because that denotes the group of inner automorphisms of $G$. Elements of order a power of a prime $p$ are just called $p$-elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Quang Hong said right away, this does not hold. Making it concrete with the following example.
The matrices
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{rr}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right)\qquad\text{and}\qquad
B=\left(\begin{array}{rr}1&0\\-1&1\end{array}\right)
$$
both have order $p$. Their product
$$
AB=\left(\begin{array}{rr}0&1\\-1&1\end{array}\right)
$$
is of order six  (unless $p=2$ in which case the order is three). I'm leaving the verification of that to you.

---

The set of all the elements of order a power of $p$ is the union of $p$-Sylow subgroups. This is a subgroup if and only if there is exactly one $p$-Sylow subgroup $P$. But in that case $P$ would be a normal subgroup of $G=SL_2(\Bbb{F}_{p^n})$. But it is well known that when $p^n>3$ the only non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$ is the subgroup of scalar matrices $=Z(G)$.